# Load Data lazily from firestore document in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, lazy-loading

For performance increase I want to load the data from a firestore document lazily. Therefore I use a PaginatedDataTable. In the rowList I have all the data from a firestore document which I want to show in the PaginatedDataTable. My question is does the lazy Loading from PaginatedDataTable work with Firestore?

```
/// DataTable Source
class DTS extends DataTableSource {
  List<DataRow> rowList;
  DTS(List<DataRow> rowList) {
    this.rowList = rowList;
  }

  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return this.rowList[index];
  }

  @override
  int get rowCount =>
      this.rowList.length;

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey Dalon. Did you get anywhere with this? I tried to help with answer below. Did you see that, and did it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can quickly tell the standard `PaginatedDataTable`/`DataTableSource`  classes don't natively support Firestore or any specific data source, but you'll have to implement those bindings yourself.

Explaining how to do that is a bit beyond what we can typically do here on Stack Overflow, but this [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+paginateddatatable+firestore+pagination) shows some promising results.